# cURL parse divs class data from other pages

Tags: php, laravel, parsing, curl

how to parse data from others website classes? Thats my code:

```
public function index()
    {            
        $response = Curl::to('http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=400874421')->get();    
        return dd($response);
    }
```

In example I need score, what commands will filter the code that the score will only be left?

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. Try something yourself first, and when you get stuck, we're happy to help.

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: You can use for example Regular Expressions to parse the $response text.

Check this tutorial
https://regexone.com/references/php

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of html parsers that can do this, though I would recommend Symfony DomCrawler Component.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html

```
$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$crawler = $crawler->filter('.score-class');
```